# Moving a view using bias according to height of keyboard [Constraint layout]

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am making an app in which I have decided to use Constraint layout. In the proposed design there is a button in the bottom right corner and it needs to move up with the keyboard when it appears as shown:

[image]

I am able to move the button up by programattically setting its vertical bias:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.setVerticalBias(buttonNext.getId(), (float) 0);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

But I want to move the button exactly above the keyboard as shown in the above figure. Upon searching I have found some solutions to find the height of the keyboard. But I don't know what calculation am I supposed to do between the bias and keyboard height. I am not sure about the unit which used for bias (percentage maybe? because in editor its value is from 1 - 100) and the keyboard height will be in dps.

If anyone can help me with my logic or propose some other solution to create the above shown layout, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

add this in activity tag

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve that behavior by setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` attribute for the `activity` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The example 'activity_main.xml' layout (using `ConstraintLayout-1.1.0`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result:

[image: keyboard_off]
[image: keybooard_on]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. 
I have tried this thing but it doesn't work if I hide notification bar (either through theme or programmatically)
Can you further suggest something to solve this issue? Because according to the UI design i have been provided, there should be no notification and title bar.